# "Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple" on DecimalField update

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    debt = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 2)
```

When I try to update already existing Invoice:

```
invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=invoice_id)
invoice.debt = '0'
invoice.save()
```

I get following error:

```
'Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple. The list or tuple should have exactly three elements.'
```

I tried

```
invoice.debt = 0,
invoice.debt = Decimal('0'),
invoice.debt = 0.0,
invoice.debt = Decimal('0.0')
```

always the same error on

```
invoice.save()
```

Any ideas?
Django 1.10.4, Python 3.4.3, Database in use MySQL 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put a comma after the assigned value, so Python turns it into a tuple of one element!

```
invoice.debt = 0,  # == (0,)
invoice.debt = Decimal('0'),  #  == (Decimal('0'),)
invoice.debt = 0.0,  # == (0.0,)
invoice.debt = Decimal('0.0')
```

Comment: Exactly, I noticed only after posting the question:

Comment: I think it's time to finally have some sleep :D